# Inline-script hash or nonce not accepted by CSP

Tags: python, flask, hashcode, content-security-policy, inline-scripting

I am developing a Flask App and it uses Flask-Talisman to incorporate a CSP. I wanted to create an inline script in one of my templates and instead of adding 'unsafe-inline' to the 'script-src' array of the CSP which could be potentially harmful to XSS attacks, I wanted to use either a hash or a nonce to allow the script. I copied the hash given in the error message of the console in dev tools on Opera and placed it inside my 'script-src' array of the CSP (in the **init**.py file). However, the CSP won't accept the hash for some reason and I don't know how to fix it. I also tried this with a nonce and the same issue occurred. This is the console output (I removed the hash for security reasons):

```
The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: 'sha256-(hash goes here)'. 
It will be ignored.
```

And here is my CSP in **init**.py:

```
csp = {
    "default-src": [
        "'self'",
        'https://www.youtube.com',
        'https://img.youtube.com'
    ],
    'script-src': [ 'sha256-(hash goes here)',
                    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js',
                    'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js',
                    'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'],
    'style-src': ["'self'",'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `hash` and a `nonce` needs to be in quotes, so you should replace this:

```
'script-src': [ 'sha256-(hash goes here)',
```

with this:

```
'script-src': [ "'sha256-(hash goes here)'",
```

similar to how you are including `'self'`.

Note also that flask-talisman has `nonce` support built in, so doesn't need to be manually specified. It will be added automatically. See this example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman#example-6